# Internal server 500 error

Tags: php, excel, apache

In my PHP application,Server throwing "500 Internal server error" while exporting huge size of excel document. But the file getting download successfully.

Anyone please help me to rectify this problem.

Comment: turn on error displaying, may be its memory limit issue.

Comment: I increased my memory limit also still im getting this problem

Comment: You can turn on error reporting to see whats wrong. The setting 'error_reporting' must be 'E_ALL' in PHP.ini and 'display_errors' should be '1'. You need to restart apache (or any other webserver you use) in order for it to work.

Comment: I would suggest to check the error log on apache to see if you are getting something in there.

Comment: or add "error_reporting(E_ALL);" to the top of your php page to enable errors

Comment: Why don't people ever look at the messages the server spits out but always try to _guess_ what is going on instead? no sense in flying in the blind: look at the log files. That is where the server says what the problem is.

Comment: @arkascha you are correct. Im getting this problem in server . I dont have the apache server access

Comment: Is there any possiblity via .htaccess?

Comment: Sounds like a hosted system. In that case consult your hosting provider what means he offers to get that information. There are many possible variants, it is up to him to decide what he offers. And don't make the mistake to say yourself: this is not worth it, I will somehow find out this time. Solve this problem now, since you will always run into the same problem otherwise. When programming, you need to know what is happening.